# How to remove category from wordpress url?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, permalinks

I am new to wordpress so i am facing a problem in removing /category/ from wordpress URL

```
http://domain/category/category-name
```

So i would like to know how to remove /category/ from the url. I have tried various solutions like

```
Go to Settings >> Permalinks and select Custom and enter: /%category%/%postname%/
Next set your Category Base to /
```

But even after doing this i am not able to remove the /category/ from the URL.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can use plugin for this.

Comment: @Khushboo yes plugins may solve my problem but i am not allowed to use any plugins.

Comment: But I think plugin will be a better solution while doing using our own code

Comment: @Khushboo: Yes it will surely solve the problem. But according to the requirement i am not supposed to use any plugins.. If you have any custom code kindly share with me.

Comment: try to follow this :- http://wpcentury.com/remove-category-best-options/

Answer (score 0):

Backup your .htacces file and try add this one. Please note the code is not tested.

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.yourblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your wordpress menu to settings. Go to permalinks and select Custom structure to choose what you need to do. If you .htaccess is rewriteable it will do it automatically and you can test around. If it isn't